# Converting arrays to objects to automate array_key_exists()

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I need my code to not throw any notices, so I've written a little class to access arrays without having to worry about undefined indexes all the time.

```
class ArrayAsObject
{
  private $array;

  public function __construct(&$array) {
    $this->array = &$array;
  }

  public function __get($key)
  {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $this->array)) {
      return $this->array[$key];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

$fruits = array ('apples' => 42);
$fruits = new ArrayAsObject($fruits);

echo $fruits->apples;  // 42
echo $fruits->lemons;  // null
```

I'm just wondering if this has any unintended consequences, or can I use this for any array and can live happily ever after?

Comment: PHP has inplementet a class like this, I would extend from this class: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php

Comment: It depends. Maybe the better answer is that you need to standardise your data model so you can be *sure* the indices exist. Maybe you should be using classes to model your data instead of arrays. Yes, your solution is one crutch which helps with this particular problem. Maybe it is exactly the crutch you need in your particular situation. But maybe you're missing the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would extend from the [ArrayObject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) class like this:

```
class MyArrayObject extends ArrayObject{

    public function offsetGet($name) {
        if($this->offsetExists($name))
            return parent::offsetGet($name);
    }
}
```

with the function `offsetGet()` you can access your Array data, so if you call `$myObjectArray['test']` the function is called. And then if you check with `offsetExists()` if the key is seted you will return the value. else the result will be null

**EDIT:**

And if you want to use this also as an object, you need to add these 2 functions:

```
public function __get($name){
    return $this->offsetGet($name);
}

public function __set($name, $value){
    $this->offsetSet($name, $value);
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. This is better in every way. I don't even have to rewrite my code to use objects now.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
$arr = array ('apples' => 42);
$fruits = new ArrayAsObject($arr);
```

instead of

```
$fruits = ArrayAsObject(array ('apples' => 42));
```

#### What was the mistake ?

You didn't use the new keyword and you directly passed the array (*Only variables can be passed by reference*) which will result in a notice.

Comment: I deleted my comment, it was before the edit. It does not matter, because it was example, and there were no related problems reported from the OP :)

Comment: @RoyalBg, Nah you will run into a notice. As the array was directly subjected.

Comment: I see. But what is the reference point here. If you have `$fruits->apples = 100;` you won't really change the array? `var_dump($arr);` will still show 42?